# Проблема с pool-connection

Tags: api, rust, actix-web, connection-pool

Недавно начал изучать Rust и писать небольшую web-api программу. По учебнику по расту, создал пул подключений, программа запускается, но отправляя get запрос, получаю ошибку. Сбрасывает соединение, как думаете, что это может быть ?

Main.rc:

```
use lib::ThreadPool;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::net::TcpStream;

    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap();
    let pool = ThreadPool::new(5);

    for stream in listener.incoming().take(100) {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        pool.execute(|| {
            handle_connection(stream);
        });
    }

    println!("Shutting down.");


fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
    stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();
    stream.flush().unwrap();
}
```

lib.rc :

```
use std::{
    sync::{mpsc, Arc, Mutex},
    thread,
};

pub struct ThreadPool {
    workers: Vec<Worker>,
    sender: Option<mpsc::Sender<Job>>,
}

type Job = Box<dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static>;

impl ThreadPool {

    pub fn new(size: usize) -> ThreadPool {
        assert!(size > 0);

        let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();

        let receiver = Arc::new(Mutex::new(receiver));

        let mut workers = Vec::with_capacity(size);

        for id in 0..size {
            workers.push(Worker::new(id, Arc::clone(&receiver)));
        }

        ThreadPool {
            workers,
            sender: Some(sender),
        }
    }

    pub fn execute<F>(&self, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce() + Send + 'static,
    {
        let job = Box::new(f);

        self.sender.as_ref().unwrap().send(job).unwrap();
    }
}

impl Drop for ThreadPool {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        drop(self.sender.take());

        for worker in &mut self.workers {
            println!("Shutting down worker {}", worker.id);

            if let Some(thread) = worker.thread.take() {
                thread.join().unwrap();
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Worker {
    id: usize,
    thread: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl Worker {
    fn new(id: usize, receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Job>>>) -> Worker {
        let thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let message = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv();

            match message {
                Ok(job) => {
                    println!("Worker {id} got a job; executing.");

                    job();
                }
                Err(_) => {
                    println!("Worker {id} disconnected; shutting down.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        Worker {
            id,
            thread: Some(thread),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Данный сервер не создаёт никакого ответа. Поэтому после отправки клиентом HTTP-запроса соединение повисает, а если клиент это браузер, он сбрасывает такое соединение.